# CMake Error at cmake/feature_defs.cmake:24 (find_package): in setting setup of people-counter project using opentoolkit

Tags: cmake, intel

I am trying to setup [people-counter](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/people-counter) project using `intel openvino toolkit` and I got this error:

```
root@d243f6716582:/opt/intel/computer_vision_sdk_2018.3.343/deployment_tools/inference_engine/samples# sudo cmake    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release /opt/intel/computer_vision_sdk_2018.3.343/deployment_tools/inference_engine/samples/

-- Looking for inference engine configuration file at: /opt/intel/computer_vision_sdk_2018.3.343/deployment_tools/inference_engine/share

-- /etc/*-release distrib: Ubuntu 16.04
-- Host CPU features:
--   3DNOW not supported
--   3DNOWEXT not supported
--   ABM not supported
--   ADX not supported
--   AES not supported
--   AVX supported
--   AVX2 not supported
--   AVX512CD not supported
--   AVX512F not supported
--   AVX512ER not supported
--   AVX512PF not supported
--   BMI1 not supported
--   BMI2 not supported
 --   CLFSH supported
--   CMPXCHG16B supported
--   CX8 supported
--   ERMS not supported
--   F16C not supported
--   FMA not supported
--   FSGSBASE not supported
--   FXSR supported
--   HLE not supported
--   INVPCID not supported
--   LAHF supported
--   LZCNT not supported
--   MMX supported
--   MMXEXT not supported
 --   MONITOR supported
 --   SYSCALL supported
 --   TBM not supported
  --   XOP not supported
  --   XSAVE supported
  CMake Warning at cmake/feature_defs.cmake:22 (find_package):
 By not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
 asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" (requested
   version 3.3) with any of the following names:

   OpenCVConfig.cmake
   opencv-config.cmake

 Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
 "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If   "OpenCV"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:101 (include)


CMake Error at cmake/feature_defs.cmake:24 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
 asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV", but
  CMake did not find one.

 Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" (requested
  version 3.3) with any of the following names:

   OpenCVConfig.cmake
    opencv-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OpenCV"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
 MakeLists.txt:101 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
 See also "/opt/intel/computer_vision_sdk_2018.3.343/deployment_tools    /inference_engine/samples/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Please explain this error and it can help me lot.

Comment: Do you have OpenCV installed anywhere?

Comment: No, in project says that opencv is not essentialy require it is optional .

Comment: Are you sure you don't need an extra option to tell it not to use OpenCV?  Pretty obviously it's looking for OpenCV.

Comment: so how to install opencv in docker container ?it is same as normal way ? please give a link that  how to install opencv if you can

Comment: @Peter Cordes : in a folder CV_sdk_2018.3.343/opencv/share/OpenCV means Opencv file have been there so how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is that CMake cannot find a FindOpenCV.cmake file, because cmake doesn't include one out of the box. Therefore you need to find one and put it where cmake can find it:
 if you have
CMakeLists.txt and cmake-modules/FindOpenCV.cmake
Then you should do a
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake-modules)
in your CMakeLists.txt file before you do a find_package(OpenCV)

You need to fill the OpenCV_DIR variable with the path of opencv (containing the OpenCVConfig.cmake file)

export OpenCV_DIR=

Answer (score 0):

Initialize OpenVINO first and do cmake

**source /bin/setupvars.sh**